# How to remove item from array and save it in one command?

Tags: javascript

How to remove an element of an array and have that removed element saved in a variable:

```
var item = arr.remove(index)
```

Comment: `Array.prototype.splice()`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use [Array.prototype.splice](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/splice) for this purpose:

```js
const arr = ['a', 'b', 'c'];
const removed = arr.splice(1, 1).pop();
console.log(arr) // ['a', 'c'];
console.log(removed) // 'b'
```

Note that in the example above, `splice` is chained with [Array.prototype.pop](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/pop) - that's because `splice`, as mentioned by @Andreas, always returns an `Array`, so `pop` is used to extract the single value from `Array` returned by `splice`.

Comment: Thanks! Doesn't `.pop()` return the last item in array? how does this work?

Comment: @Aurimas You are right, `pop` returns the last item in an array. And we are good with it, since previous `splice` method call returned an array that contains only a single value. When you are calling `pop` on an array that has a single value - this single value is being returned.

Answer (score 2):

What you're looking for is [`splice`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/splice). This takes as parameters the index of the item to remove, and the count of items from that to take out. Because you only want to remove 1 item, the 2nd parameter will always be 1. Splice also returns as an array, so we're indexing that `[0]` to get just the contents.

```
var arr = ['a','b','c'];
var item = arr.splice(1,1)[0]; // 'b'
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe something like this?

```
Array.prototype.remove=function(i){
    var item=this[i]
    this.splice(i,1)
    return item
}

arr=[1,2,3]
item=arr.remove(1)
console.log(item) //2
console.log(arr) //[1,3]
```

I hope that this will help you!

Comment: [Why is extending native objects a bad practice?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14034180/why-is-extending-native-objects-a-bad-practice)

Comment: `var item = ...` + `return item` are not necessary as `.splice()` does already return the removed item(s).